# java-script cookie input field string display error

Tags: javascript, cookies

Hello i am currently trying to get this to work so that when the user visits the page for the webpage for the first time it asks them to enter a name into the input box and then future visits will display their name with SweetAlert.
my attempt bellow

```
function checkCookie() {
var user=getCookie("username");
if (user != "") {
    swal("Welcome again " + user);
} else {

    user = prompt; swal({
            title: 'Input Username',
            html: '<p><input id="input-field">',
            showCancelButton: true,
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            allowOutsideClick: false
        });
```

However when i try to load the page for the first time it displays the input box but after entering text and reloading the page it shows this

> Welcome again function prompt() { [native code] }

The Full js file is located here for review

> https://joshsmotions.co.uk/scripts/cookie-script.js
>
> The domain i am implementing this on is https://joshsmotions.co.uk

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I see. `user` shouldn't be equal to `prompt`. It should be equal to `prompt()`.